# Error: "You need to specify a way to create Tab indicator"

Tags: android

I am creating a TabHost which is a Tab view in a fragment. The sub fragment will be connected to my main fragment called `fragment_usage`. After running, it keeps giving me this error:

> you need to specify a way to create tab indicator.

```
MAIN FRAGMENT(FRAGMENT_USAGE)

package com.example.redir.wealthtrack;


import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;

import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.Tabs.Tag1;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class UsageFragment extends Fragment  {


    public UsageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usage, container, false);
        TabHost tab = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tab.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Tab1);
        tab.addTab(spec1);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 2");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Tab2);
        tab.addTab(spec2);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec3 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 3");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Tab3);
        tab.addTab(spec3);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec4 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 4");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.Tab4);
        tab.addTab(spec4);


                return view;


    }
}
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLyii.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **spec1-> spec2,spec3,spec4**; Be careful when you are copying :)

```
    TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.Tab1);
    tab.addTab(spec1);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2 .setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec2 .setContent(R.id.Tab2);
    tab.addTab(spec2);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec3 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec3 .setIndicator("Tab 3");
    spec3 .setContent(R.id.Tab3);
    tab.addTab(spec3);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec4 = tab.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
    spec4 .setIndicator("Tab 4");
    spec4 .setContent(R.id.Tab4);
    tab.addTab(spec4);
```